# Using conditional compilation in ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cargo-contract

My question is quite simple - can I use conditional compilation via `cfg` attribute macros in ink! contracts?

Example:

Cargo.toml

```
cross_contract_emit = []
```

lib.rs

```
            #[cfg(not(feature = "cross_contract_emit"))]
            Self::emit_event(
                self.env(),
                Event::Event1(Event1 {
                    who: caller,
                    value: self.value,
                }),
            );

            #[cfg(feature = "cross_contract_emit")]
            build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call_type(Call::new().callee(AccountId::from(EMITTER_PUBKEY)))
                .exec_input(
                    ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(EMIT_FLIP_EVENT_SELECTOR))
                        .push_arg(caller)
                        .push_arg(self.value),
                )
                .returns::<()>()
                .fire();
```

and I want to compile & upload two versions of the contract, once by passing the `--features "cross_contract_emit"` feature flag, and once without.

Comment: It is possible [conditional compiling in ink!](https://use.ink/4.0.0-alpha.1/faq#what-does-the-cfg_attrnotfeature--std-no_std-at-the-beginning-of-each-contract-mean)

Comment: That's not what this documentation describes, it specifies how to compile to std and non-std (aka wasm) environments. It says nothing about passing own feature flags for conditional compilation

Comment: There is [`mother contract in example`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/mother). Exactly your question Scenario for conditional compiling. [read this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1458)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/527, currently there is no way of conditionally compiling contract. This feature will be added in the next ink! 4.0 release.

I have attempted to implement conditional compilation, but it doesn't work in intended way, so we had to revert the PR: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1479

Please bear with us :)